# JSF rendering browser dependency

Tags: jsf, html-rendering

Is there a browser dependency for rendering JSF components? Using a chrome plugin and google chrome the JSF pages seemed to render a lot faster while compared to IE 6, is there any specific reason for this? 
I know html runs in web browser.. and jsf runs on server and creates the html... my question was whether certain browsers are more tuned to the way jsf renders html (the way tags and html component names, ids, scripts, etc are created favours certain browsers) to them making it faster!!!

Comment: JSF doesn't run in webbrowser. JSF runs in webserver and produces HTML. That HTML in turn runs in webbrowser.

Comment: I know html runs in web browser.. and jsf runs on server and creates the html... my question was whether certain browsers are more tuned to the way jsf renders html to them making it faster!!!

Comment: Why do you think that it depends on HTML code and not on browser itself?

Comment: Look at this - http://www.ajaxline.com/browsers-performance-in-dependence-of-html-coding

Comment: I dont quite understand why this is closed in a public forum and so many negative feedback... I actually have a situation where in a JSF site renders faster on chrome and slower on IE, so I wanted to explore and understand if there is such a relationship existing... where certain types of html rendering makes the JSF - html -  browser relationship stronger in certain scenarios... answer "No" if that is not the case... dont do this!!!

Comment: JSF sites tend to generate bloated HTML (lots of tables in tables, in tables...) and Chrome is much faster at rendering that mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

All JSF components are rendered into HTML ones

Its Just that Chrome is much faster than IE 6 , that's all

---

[Which of the big five Web Browsers is the Best? (Review)](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/networking/which-of-the-big-five-web-browsers-is-the-best-review/1612)

The above link is a bit outdated , but it summarize the general idea (IE is slow)

> JSF doesn't run in webbrowser. JSF runs in webserver and produces HTML
>   (BalusC)

This means that the browser only gets the HTML and not even aware of the HTML being JSF components before...

Comment: OK thanks. I know html runs in web browser.. and jsf runs on server and creates the html... my question was whether certain browsers are more tuned to the way jsf renders html to them making it faster!!

Comment: No , cause the browser has nothing to do with the JSF rendering the html elements out of its JSF components